# Structuring a RESTful API for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: json, database, rest, many-to-many, api-design

I'm currently creating an API for an application which has three types of data; `Files`, `Tags` and `Persons`. These are all routinely linked; a `File` has many `Tags` and `Persons` attached to it.

The problem is, I don't know how to actually connect them using a RESTful API. `Persons` and `Tags` are essential to a `File`, so they are returned with it automatically, without any further requests.

Here's an example of the structure I'm looking at right now for `Files`:

```
GET /files
GET /files/:id
POST /files
PUT /files/:id
PATCH /files/:id
```

And for `Tags`:

```
GET /tags
GET /tags/:id
POST /tags
PUT /tags/:id
PATCH /tags/:id
```

And for `Persons`:

```
GET /persons
GET /persons/:id
POST /persons
PUT /persons/:id
PATCH /persons/:id
```

As you can see, they're all exactly the same, with the intention of making my API easy to document. The problem is, though, with many-to-many relations, I don't know how to link a given `Tag` or `Person` to a `File`.

I was considering this:

```
POST /files/:id/tags
DELETE /files/:id/tags/:id
```

But that seems a bit clunky.

What is the ideal structure for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

> These are all routinely linked; a File has many Tags and Persons attached to it.

Then the `PATCH /files/:id` endpoint seems like a good place:

```
PATCH /files/:id
{
    "PersonIds": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "TagIds": [ 4, 5 ]
}
```

This will update the `File` associations with `Persons` and `Tags` and leave the other properties of the file untouched (which is the point of the `PATCH` verb - partial update).

Comment: That's actually a good way of doing it, but the problem is I'm not sure how to unlink a single item doing it that way.

Comment: Indeed this will not be possible with this approach unless you `GET` the `File` resource beforehand so that you have information about its associations with the other resources. Then your initial design is better suited for this situation even if it feels clunky.

Comment: Damnit. I'll take a very careful look at both, and at some other APIs I was examining, and I'll decide what works best.